# Пропадает возможность делать слайс по периоду после объединения двух DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, sql-merge

Имею два DataFrame (res, descr) со следующим набором колонок:

```
MultiIndex([(          'bucket', '2020-01'),
            (          'bucket', '2020-02'),])
```

Момент, на который здесь необходимо обратить внимание, это тип данных второго элемента MultiIndex, а именно `pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period`:

```
type(descr.columns[0][1]) # pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period
type(res.columns[0][1])   # pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period
```

В нужный момент объединяю массивы:

```
total_df = res.merge(descr, how='left', left_on='calculationID', right_on='calculationID', suffixes=('_res', '_descr'), sort=True)
```

Полученный сводный массив имеет такой набор колонок:

```
MultiIndex([(                'bucket', 2020-01),
            (                'bucket', 2020-02),])
```

То есть, визуально, второй элемент MultiIndex уже не заключен в кавычки.
При этом, тип этого элемента по-прежнему `pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period`:

```
type(total_df.columns[0][1]) # pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period
```

**Проблема заключается в том, что в объединенном DataFrame пропадает возможность делать слайс по периоду во втором элементе.**

До объединения датафреймов следующая конструкция позволяет отфильтровать только нужные месяцы:

```
descr.head(1).loc[:, idx[:, idx['2020-01': '2020-02']]]
```

Результат:

```
              confiscation_cost    days_for_confiscation
period        2020-01   2020-02    2020-01   2020-02
calculationID
ID 1          10        20         1         2
```

Если же пытаюсь тем же способом отобрать в объединенном DataFrame столбцы, ловлю ошибку `KeyError: '2020-01'`:

```
In: total_df.head(1).loc[:, idx[:, idx['2020-01': '2020-02']]]
Out: ...KeyError: '2020-01'
```

***UPD1*** код для генерации тестовых массивов:

```
res = {
    ('bucket', pd.Period('2020-01', 'M')): {'ID1': '1.0', 'ID2': '1.0', 'ID3': '1.0', 'ID4': '1.0', 'ID5': '1.0'},
    ('bucket', pd.Period('2020-02', 'M')): {'ID1': '1.0', 'ID2': '1.0', 'ID3': '1.0', 'ID4': '1.0', 'ID5': '1.0'},
    ('bucket', pd.Period('2020-03', 'M')): {'ID1': '1.0', 'ID2': '1.0', 'ID3': '1.0', 'ID4': '1.0', 'ID5': '1.0'},
    ('bucket', pd.Period('2020-04', 'M')): {'ID1': '1.0', 'ID2': '1.0', 'ID3': '1.0', 'ID4': '1.0', 'ID5': '1.0'},
      }
res = pd.DataFrame(res)
res.index.rename('calculationID', inplace=True)

descr = {
    ('mark', pd.Period('2020-01', 'M')): {'ID1': 'm1', 'ID2': 'm1', 'ID3': 'm2', 'ID4': 'm2', 'ID5': 'm1'},
    ('mark', pd.Period('2020-02', 'M')): {'ID1': 'm1', 'ID2': 'm2', 'ID3': 'm3', 'ID4': 'm4', 'ID5': 'm2'},
    ('mark', pd.Period('2020-03', 'M')): {'ID1': 'm1', 'ID2': 'm2', 'ID3': 'm3', 'ID4': 'm4', 'ID5': 'm2'},
    ('mark', pd.Period('2020-04', 'M')): {'ID1': 'm1', 'ID2': 'm2', 'ID3': 'm3', 'ID4': 'm4', 'ID5': 'm2'},
}
descr = pd.DataFrame(descr)
descr.index.rename('calculationID', inplace=True)
```

Comment: можете привести в вопросе код для создания небольшого, но воспроизводимого DF?

Comment: @MaxU, добавил код для создания воспроизводимого DF

Comment: для примера из вопроса `descr.head(1).loc[:, idx[:, idx['2020-01': '2020-02']]]` - тоже не отрабатывает - `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Костылем" является обращение в слайсе через pd.Period:

```
total_df.loc[:, idx[:, pd.Period('2020-01'):pd.Period('2020-02')]]
```

Результат:

```
              bucket            mark
              2020-01  2020-02  2020-01  2020-02
calculationID
ID1           1.0      1.0      m1       m1
ID2           1.0      1.0      m1       m2
ID3           1.0      1.0      m2       m3
ID4           1.0      1.0      m2       m4
ID5           1.0      1.0      m1       m2
```

В идеале конечно понять почему в исходных массивах (до объединения) все работает без дополнительного явного преобразования строки в объект класса Period.